# Являются ли родственными слова "графика" и "граффити"?

Tags: словообразование

-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово **графика** пришло в русский язык из греческого (grapho 'режу, царапаю, пишу'), возможно через немецкий и латинский (нем. Graphik «графика» заимствовано из лат. яз. graphica). 
Слово **граффити** в русский пришло из итальянского (graffiti < graffito 'нацарапанный'). В свою очередь, итальянское graffito происходит от латинского graphica, заимствованного из греческого языка (греч. γραφειν «писать».). Понятно, что идея письма или рисунка путем нацарапывания прослеживается в обоих словах. Конечно, слова родственные.
(Использованы этимологические словари Фасмера, Цыганенко, словарь иностранных слов)

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос непростой. В греческом-то у слов общий корень, тут спорить не о чем.
Но вот можно ли их в связи с этим считать слова родственными в русском... Не знаю. 
Поняитие родственности слов - все-таки компетенция одного языка и если слов пришли в данный язык разными путями, тем более из разных языков-источников, боюсь, о родственности в обычном понимании термина говорить нельзя. Как минимум - оговорить, что это родственность имеет место на уровне первоисточника, а в русский попали совершенно разными путями.

Comment: Согласна с вашим мнением. Родственность заимствованных слов в русском языке - отдельный вопрос. Тем более, что в русский данные слова пришли разными путями. Потому я и говорю о родственности слов (исторической), а не о том, что они однокоренные в современном русском языке.